# Replication monitor verbose history

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactional

I have set up transactional replication. After setup I have change agent profile as attached file. But I am not getting verbose history in replication monitor.

[image]

Comment: Is this about SQL Server, the Microsoft product?

Comment: Did you restart the agent after making the change? Also, are you *sure* you want verbose history? In my experience, you only do this if you're actively troubleshooting an issue (which you may be…).

Comment: Thanks Ben, after restarting Agent I started to get verbose histroy.

Answer (score 0):

Restart agent and replication, verbose history will be started to show.